# Прерывание 10h, функция 06h. Прокрутка строки вверх

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, прерывания

Я пытаюсь реализовать сдвиг строки вверх. И сдвиг то у меня получился, но символы в этой новой строке не выводятся, курсор исчез и ничего не происходит. Может я забыла что-то учесть? Для написания кода использовала `FASM`. У меня идёт счётчик

```
cmp cx, 2001
je ScrollLine
```

и когда он достигает 2001 (счётчик от 1), то перехожу на ScrollLine, где вот что:

```
mov ah, 06h
mov al, 1
mov bh, 07      
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, 184Fh 
int 10h
ret
```

Comment: А почему `je`, а не `call`? У вас ведь `ScrollLine` заканчивается инструкцией `ret`.

Comment: @Алла, нужно больше кода. Из того что есть, не понятно, то ли и правда там `call` должен быть, то ли у вас и `cmp` и `je` внутри процедуры, и все так и должно быть.

Comment: А позиция курсора при этом как меняется?